# Apache Spark parquet partition

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, parquet

I am trying to save DataFrame in Amazon S3 parquet folder using date as partition key. I am loading data day by day.

The first time I save it I see partition folder (i.e. "txDate=20160714").

When I am processing next files, they all go to "txDate=__HIVE_DEFAULT_PARTITION__": [see parquet Hive partitions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wpVdW.png)

txDate is int

I am using Databricks platform, Apache Spark 1.6.2 and Hadoop 2.

My code is in Python (Pyspark)

```
# initial save
df_newTx.write.partitionBy(['txDate']).format('parquet').mode('append').save("/mnt/dm.Inv/f_Tx.parquet")

# incremental save
df_tx_all.write.partitionBy(['txDate']).format('parquet').mode('append').save("/mnt/dm.Inv/f_Tx.parquet")
```

Comment: `__HIVE_DEFAULT_PARTITION__` is reserved for NULL values.